# When to split up action controllers?

Tags: zend-framework, model-view-controller

I have a dashboard action controller which displays an agenda class containing events, some graphs, and other widgets.  Currently the dashboard controller handles advancing the agenda back/forward by week.  Should I have a separate agenda controller?  What is your general rule of thumb in determining when to split up action controllers?

Answer (score 0):

It's depend on your client side code . If you see liferay dashboard or if you know portlet JSR in J2EE . portlet (abstraction unit (manageable part) of dashboard) has different mode (view , edit , preferences ,... ). if load and switch between modes handled with client side code . you need a template for each mode . then you need a action for each portlet that has two responsibility . 
1- load data 
2- merge data and template and send it on response of ajax request